# Do bears get a taste for human flesh?

Tags: nutrition, zoology

I'm sure I've heard similar stories regarding dogs and even hamsters, but in [this Guardian story](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/jun/13/warning-four-killed-bear-attacks-akita-japan) a vet says:

> Takeshi Komatsu, a local vet, said it was possible that the four were killed by the same bear. “After tasting human flesh (for the first time), the bear may have realised that it can eat them,” Komatsu told Kyodo news agency.

Is this opinion based on sound scientific evidence?

Comment: Its probably not a "taste" in the sense of a food preference. Its more likely that, having found a successful new strategy for obtaining food, the bear applies what it has learned and does it again. Bears are quite intelligent and adaptable.